How to programmatically validate a form before proceeding to the next step in a multi-step form using zod & react-hook-form
So i have a form in my app that has multiple steps, but at the moment if the user skips some steps and tries submitting, the form won't submit because they skipped non-optional fields but the errors show at the previous steps so the user won't know that some values aren't filled in.
So what i was thinking of is, validating the form as the user progresses through the form so they cannot go to the next step without having completed the current ones.
What is a good approach on doing this using Zod?
My form:
"use client";

import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { z } from "zod";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { createApplication } from "@/app/applications/actions";
import { useUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { findUserByClerkId } from "@/app/actions";
import { Switch } from "@/components/ui/switch";
import {
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormControl,
  FormMessage,
  Form,
  FormDescription,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import {
  Activity,
  Briefcase,
  Building2,
  Calendar,
  File,
  FileText,
  Hash,
  Link,
  MapPin,
  Paperclip,
  StickyNote,
  X,
  UserPlus,
  LinkedinIcon,
  User,
} from "lucide-react";
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectItem,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from "../ui/select";
import { Textarea } from "../ui/textarea";
import { uploads } from "./upload-files-page";
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { BasicJobInfo } from "./form-fields/basic-job-info";
import { ApplicationDetails } from "./form-fields/application-details";
import { AdditionalInformation } from "./form-fields/additional-information";

type FormValues = z.infer<typeof formSchema>;

const formSchema = z.object({
  jobTitle: z
    .string()
    .min(2, { message: "Job Title must be at least 2 characters long" }),
  companyName: z
    .string()
    .min(2, { message: "Company Name must be at least 2 characters long" }),
  jobLocation: z
    .string()
    .min(2, { message: "Job Location must be at least 2 characters long" }),
  jobDescription: z
    .string()
    .min(5, { message: "Job Description must be at least 5 characters long" }),
  jobType: z.string(),
  applicationDate: z.string(),
  applicationStatus: z.string(),
  applicationLink: z.string().optional(),
  applicationNotes: z.string().optional(),
  jobReferenceNumber: z.string().optional(),
  applicationDeadline: z
    .string()
    .optional()
    .refine((value) => !value || /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/.test(value), {
      message: "Application Deadline must be a valid date (YYYY-MM-DD)",
    }),
  resume: z.string().optional(),
  coverLetter: z.string().optional(),
  referral: z.boolean().default(false),
  referralSource: z.string().optional(),
  referralContact: z.string().optional(),
});

export const referralInfo = (form: any) => {
  return (
    <div className="space-y-6 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-sm">
      <FormItem className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between rounded-lg border p-4">
        <div className="space-y-0.5">
          <FormLabel className="text-base flex items-center">
            <UserPlus className="mr-2 h-5 w-5 text-indigo-500" />
            Referral
          </FormLabel>
          <FormDescription className="text-sm text-gray-500">
            Do you have a referral for this job application?
          </FormDescription>
        </div>
        <Controller
          name="referral"
          control={form.control}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
            <Switch checked={value} onCheckedChange={onChange} />
          )}
        ></Controller>
      </FormItem>

      <FormField
        control={form.control}
        name="referralSource"
        render={({ field }) => (
          <FormItem>
            <FormLabel className="flex items-center text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
              <LinkedinIcon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-500" />
              Referral Source
            </FormLabel>
            <FormControl>
              <Input
                placeholder="e.g. LinkedIn, Company Website, Job Fair"
                {...field}
                className="mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring-indigo-500"
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormDescription className="text-xs text-gray-500 mt-1">
              Where did you find this referral opportunity?
            </FormDescription>
            <FormMessage className="text-xs text-red-500 mt-1" />
          </FormItem>
        )}
      />

      <FormField
        control={form.control}
        name="referralContact"
        render={({ field }) => (
          <FormItem>
            <FormLabel className="flex items-center text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
              <User className="mr-2 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-500" />
              Referral Contact
            </FormLabel>
            <FormControl>
              <Input
                placeholder="e.g. John Doe, jane@example.com"
                {...field}
                className="mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring-indigo-500"
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormDescription className="text-xs text-gray-500 mt-1">
              Name or contact information of your referral
            </FormDescription>
            <FormMessage className="text-xs text-red-500 mt-1" />
          </FormItem>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export const AddApplicationForm = ({ onOpenChange }: { onOpenChange: any }) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(0);
  const { user } = useUser();

  const { data, mutateAsync, isPending } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (formData: FormData) => createApplication(formData),
    onError: (error) => {
      return alert(error.message || "Failed to update");
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["applications"] });
      onOpenChange(false);
    },
  });

  // 1. Define your form.
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      jobTitle: "",
      companyName: "",
      jobLocation: "",
      jobDescription: "",
      jobType: "part-time",
      applicationDate: "",
      applicationStatus: "applied",
      applicationLink: "",
      applicationNotes: "",
      jobReferenceNumber: "",
      applicationDeadline: "",
      resume: "",
      coverLetter: "",
      referral: false,
      referralSource: "",
      referralContact: "",
    },
  });

  // 2. Define a submit handler.
  async function onSubmit(values: FormValues) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();

    const mongoUser = await findUserByClerkId(user?.id);
    formData.append("userId", mongoUser?._id);

    (Object.keys(values) as Array<keyof FormValues>).forEach((key) => {
      const value = values[key];
      if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
        formData.append(key, value.toString());
      }
    });

    mutateAsync(formData);
  }

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-8">
        {currentStep === 0 && BasicJobInfo(form)}
        {currentStep === 1 && ApplicationDetails(form)}
        {currentStep === 2 && AdditionalInformation(form)}
        {currentStep === 3 && uploads(form)}
        {currentStep === 4 && referralInfo(form)}
        <div className="flex justify-between">
          {currentStep > 0 ? (
            <Button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => setCurrentStep((prev) => prev - 1)}
            >
              Previous
            </Button>
          ) : (
            <div />
          )}
          {currentStep === 4 ? (
            <Button key="submit" type="submit">
              Submit
            </Button>
          ) : (
            <Button
              key="next"
              type="button"
              onClick={() => setCurrentStep((prev) => prev + 1)}
            >
              Next
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
};



I like multi step forms UX. I have created these over the time
https://ancestrypass.com/quiz
https://mehdirazanaqvi.github.io/web/

A good approach in multi step form using Zod would be to creating individual Zod schemas for each step like this :
const stepSchemas = [
      z.object({
        jobTitle: z.string().min(2, { message: "Job Title must be ..." }),
        ...
      }),
      z.object({
        jobType: z.string(),
        ...
      }),
      ...
    ];

Update your form setup to validate based on the current step :
  const form = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(stepSchemas[currentStep]),
    defaultValues: {
      ...
    }
    })

and the most importantly trigger the condition before proceeding to next step :
  const handleNextStep = async () => {
    const isValid = await form.trigger();
    if (isValid) {
      setCurrentStep((prev) => prev + 1);
    }
  };

Also there are multiple libraries like Formik and Yup for form validation and management incase you want to explore.

Thank you so much for the idea of separating the different Zod schemas. I was thinking the same, but seeing your idea helped me
